# What happened to the rear gear?

Tags: gears

I commute to work every day, 6km round trip. Everything was fine for many days.

Yesterday, I (believe successfully) switched from 2x2 to 3x7 in order to make some more intense training. I start putting effort in, and then I hear this cringy sound like the bike is shouting "don't put force on me while changing gears, you imbecile"!

Anyway, I don't know if mentioning this is relevant or not, but the fact is that after that...I had 6 gears in the derailleur instead of 7, and it was virtually impossible to pedal. I had to change the casette/cartridge.

Did a gear...break? Noone I've discussed this with, including the fixguy, has any idea how a gear vanished.

Comment: Uploading some photos and/or a short video is extremely helpful for us to diagnose problems in cases like this

Comment: Ahhh, too late since I fixed it

Comment: With a conventional derailleur style hub, it's easy to get the derailer maladjusted such that you can't reach all gears.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis could you please post an answer sharing how you fixed it ?

Comment: Well, my bike guy replaced the sprocket cassette. Not too interesting an angle, I guess. We will never learn :(

Answer (score 4):

The only way to literally lose a rear sprocket would be if it broke into pieces and fell away. Even if it came loose there is no way for it to come off without taking the rear wheel out.

Comment: It does happen sometimes. I've broken a sprocket once, as has a friend. I haven't until now heard of it happening to anyone else.